# Apache - multiple sites on one IP, domain and port with SSL

Tags: apache, virtualhost

Is it possible to run multiple apache sites on the same IP, domain and port (meaning the <VirtualHost> tags are exactly identical and no ServerName is given) while using SSL (not sure whether SSL makes a difference here)?

I would like to separate my web services into files in `etc/apache2/sites-available` to be able to activate or deactivate them on demand. Basically Apache should just take all files and string them together internally, but leave me the possibility to a2dissite certain parts.

Further clarification:
By "sites", I mean files in the `etc/apache2/sites-available` directory. "Web services" in this context are certain application like phpMyAdmin or an Etherpad which run on the Apache and whose configuration (e.g. Alias or ProxyPass) I want to write into its own configuration file ("site"),

Comment: `same IP, domain and port` and how server will decide what content to return? only if every 'site' will exist in its own folder.

Comment: @Cheery It wouldn't need to decide because all the files are mutually exclusive. As I said, it would probably just have to internally string all the settings from the same VirtualHost together.

Comment: It is possible if you're not using SSL, because SSL requires a unique IP per domain.

Comment: @Prix But I do only have one IP and one domain.

Comment: @RikuXan define `multiple sites` and what web services, don't think I am following your requirement here.

Comment: @Prix I added the information to the main question

Comment: I see, well I am not familiar with debian/ubuntu which seems the OS you're using but CentOS for example have a separated configuration file for each app and module installed which you can easily enable / disable. You should perhaps try asking your question at http://askubuntu.com/ if you're using ubuntu or a similar community towards your OS for a more specific answer since this question is related to server administration and not programming.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no.

SSL operates at a level between TCP and HTTP. But the virtual host name is sent via HTTP. So how does SSL know which certificate to use for a virtual host?

There is a way to do it - basically start up the HTTP over TCP then switch to SSL after the virtual host name (in the Host header) is sent. However this is complex, error prone and generally considered a bad idea.

Best practice is to have one IP per SSL. One machine can have multitple IP addresses, even a single network port can have mulitple IP addresses.

Comment: But I do not want do discern between virtual host names, all sites have the same IP, domain, port and virtual host name. I know that it would work technically because I can achieve the same by putting everything in one file. I do not know however if Apache allows me to split these directives in multiple files and connect them logically by the same VirtualHost.

Comment: This answer is wrong (at least nowadays). [Server Name Indication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) allows multiple SSL sites to share an IP address, even with different domains. [Browsers](https://caniuse.com/#search=SNI) and [IIS 8.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-server-name-indication-sni-ssl-scalability) all support SNI. [Apache](https://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/apache-multiple-ssl-certificates-using-sni.htm) does, too.

Comment: I agree. The technology for HTTPS has improved significantly. Some older browsers still can't manage (I'm looking at you IE6) but they are not generally worth worrying about